# Centos 7 GNOME license accepted using command line

Tags: centos7, gnome

I'm trying to install GNOME Desktop for minimal Centos 7 using ansible.

After installing packages, the reboot process stops and requires configuration for languages, time zone, license and some other preferences.

So is there a way where I can set these configurations with the command line of minimal before rebooting the system? What files do I need to edit before starting GUI to avoid doing these settings manually?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Centos 7 bug #0007177. Look at [this](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=7177#c25635) for a sed substitution to eula.py that will fix it. Though in my setup it still wanted some Q&A at next bootup wrt user account creation.